# Disable credential storage of network shared folders in windows clients

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-registry, shared-folders

How to disable credential storage of network shared folders in windows clients (maybe with a .reg key or GPO etc)? (auto-login network shared folders)

Reason: I have a "shared network folder" and I want hundreds of PCs to connect to it, but it is essential that **each time** a windows client accesses the shared network folder, enter the username and password. Windows can not store these credentials. So, i need to simplify the process.

I try this .reg key and doesn't work:

```
HKLM\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa\disabledomaincreds to 1
```

I try with [this GPO](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/uncheck-remember-my-credential-for-a-local-network/63279d34-149c-4543-a130-c71330483e73) and doesn't work:

```
Press Windows+R keys and type “gpedit.msc”. Hit Enter.
Navigate to the following location:
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
Double Click on the option:
“Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication”.
Select the radio button which says “Enabled”.
```

I tried with [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194794/how-to-make-samba-to-ask-password-on-every-access) and doesn't work:

```
Click Start >Run >type gpedit.msc
Check Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
Check "Interactive Logon: Number of Previous Logins To Cache" (if value is set to 0 then cached credentials is disabled)
```

And these solutions are not suitable to be massively implemented:

```
Click Start > Run (or press Windows key + R) then type rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

or [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/64708/how-to-disable-auto-login-for-windows-network-drives):

```
net use \\server\fileshare /username:domain\user1
net use \\fileserver\fileshare /username:domain\user2
```

**Note:**

The PCs are not in a "domain" (they are in a WORKGROUP).

There is no firewall or other active security measure in Windows clients

Comment: Is this a domain joined computer? Each solution you reference is about cached credentials. Domain connected computers aren’t using cached credentials. What is it exactly you are trying to accomplish? What is your concern you are trying to solve?

Comment: The caching is done on the computers that accessing the share, not on the server. The only way to invalidate their access is to change the password of the account used for accessing.

Comment: @Appleoddity Note: The PCs are not in a "domain" (they are in a "working group")

Comment: @ajcg Even though your computers are in a WORKGROUP they will still (in almost all cases) honor the GroupPolicy settings set via gpedit or the local policy editor. Manually creating the registry keys under \HKLM\Software\Policies will work as well. So don't be too quick to dismiss domain based solutions !